# How do I detect overflow in verilog?

Tags: verilog

So my goal is to detect overflow when adding two 64-bit variables A and B. I tried a couple things that didn't work out. At first I did:

```
          if ((A[63])== B[63]==1)
            Overflow=1;
```

That didn't work so I did:

```
if(A != (ALU_Result-B))
Overflow=1;
```

ALU_Result is my result btw. I thought that the value it held will be the first 64 bit so this equation would give the flag but this didn't work either. How do I create the flag? Also, if there is overflow, then is the carry automatically a 1?

Answer (score 1):

For unsigned numbers, overflow occurs when the sum is less than **either** of the operands.

For signed (two's complement) numbers, overflow occurs when both operands are negative, but the sum is positive, or if both operands are positive and the sum is negative.

This Verilog example uses 8 bit numbers for the unsigned case and 32 bit numbers for the signed case.  It does not matter what size the numbers are.
Check for overflow using sign of the operands and result as detailed above, and illustrated in the code below.

Verilog ex in a testbench process of adding unsigned, unsigned numbers and detecting overflow:

```
module tb();
  
reg [7:0] a_unsigned;
reg [7:0] b_unsigned;
reg [7:0] unsigned_sum;

integer a_signed;
integer b_signed;
integer signed_sum;
bit     overflow;
  
  
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Print signed
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  task printSigned(int Ain, Bin,SumIn ,logic overflow);
    $display("---- Printing Signed Check ----"); 
    $display("Ain = %0d, Bin = %0d, SumIn = %0d, overflow = %0d\n",
             Ain,Bin,SumIn,overflow);
  endtask
  
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Print unsigned
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  task printUnsigned(logic [7 : 0] a_in, b_in, sum_in ,logic overflow);
    $display("---- Printing Unsigned Check ----");
    $display("a_in = %0d, b_in = %0d, sum_in = %0d, overflow = %0d\n",
             a_in,b_in,sum_in,overflow);
  endtask  
  
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // check_signed_overflow
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  function automatic logic checkSignedOverflow (input int a_in, b_in, sum_in) ;
    reg overflow;
    if((a_in > 0 && b_in > 0 && sum_in < 0) 
       || 
         (a_in < 0 && b_in < 0 && sum_in > 0))
        overflow = 1'b1;
      else
        overflow = 1'b0;
    return overflow;
  endfunction
  
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // check_unsigned_overflow
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  function automatic logic checkUnsignedOverflow (input reg [7:0] Ain,Bin,SumIn);
    reg overflow;
      if(SumIn < Ain || SumIn < Bin)
        overflow = 1'b1;
      else
        overflow = 1'b0;  
    return overflow;
  endfunction 
  
initial
  begin
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------
  // signed overflow , add two positives get a negative
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------
  a_signed = 32'h7fffffff;
  b_signed = 32'h7fffffff;
  //
  signed_sum = a_signed + b_signed;      
  overflow = checkSignedOverflow(a_signed,a_signed,signed_sum);
  printSigned(a_signed,a_signed,signed_sum,overflow);
  #1;
      
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------
  // signed no overflow
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------
  a_signed = 32'hf;
  b_signed = 32'hf;
  //
  signed_sum = a_signed + b_signed;      
  overflow = checkSignedOverflow(a_signed,a_signed,signed_sum); 
  printSigned(a_signed,a_signed,signed_sum,overflow);
  #1;

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------
  // unsigned no overflow
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------
  a_unsigned = 25;
  b_unsigned = 25;
  //
  unsigned_sum = a_unsigned + b_unsigned;      
  overflow = checkUnsignedOverflow(a_unsigned,b_unsigned,unsigned_sum);
  printUnsigned(a_unsigned,b_unsigned,unsigned_sum,overflow);  
  #1;
      
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------
  // unsigned overflow
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------
  a_unsigned = 255;
  b_unsigned = 255;
  //
  unsigned_sum = a_unsigned + b_unsigned;      
  overflow = checkUnsignedOverflow(a_unsigned,b_unsigned,unsigned_sum); 
  printUnsigned(a_unsigned,b_unsigned,unsigned_sum,overflow);  
  #1;        
      
  $finish;
  end
  
endmodule
```

Testbench run results here:

```
xcelium> run    

a_in = 2147483647, b_in = 2147483647, sum_in = -2, overflow = 1

a_in = 15, b_in = 15, sum_in = 30, overflow = 0

a_in = 25, b_in = 25, sum_in = 50, overflow = 0

a_in = 255, b_in = 255, sum_in = 254, overflow = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The most direct way to do this is to have a temporary variable which has an extra bit so the sum does not overflow. I have shown how to handle this for unsigned numbers.  It is easy enough to expand this to signed numbers by checking for both positive and negative overflow. Synthesis tools should be smart enough to simplify this logic without you doing any bit manipulation

```
logic [63:0] A;
logic [63:0] B;
logic [64:0] A_plus_B;
logic [63:0] A_plus_B_clipped;
logic overflow;


always_comb begin
   A_plus_B = A + B;

   if(A_plus_B > 65'h0_FFFF_FFFF_FFFF_FFFF) begin
      // Overflow happened, set the flag and clip
      // the output
      overflow = 1'b1;
      A_plus_B_clipped = 64'hFFFF_FFFF_FFFF_FFFF;
   end
   else begin
      // No overflow so we can cast the result to
      // a 64-bit number
      overflow = 1'b0;
      A_plus_B_clipped = 64'(A_plus_B);
   end
end
```

Another way to do it for unsigned numbers is to directly use that extra bit as the overflow flag. This options doesn't clip your result, but I am not sure you care about that:

```
logic [63:0] A;
logic [63:0] B;
logic [63:0] A_plus_B;
logic overflow;


always_comb begin
   {overflow, A_plus_B} = A + B;
end
```